# Smooth approximation: Does the position of the "middle value" remain the same?

Tags: real-analysis, approximation, convolution, smooth-functions

Consider the function $f\colon\mathbb{R}\to\{0,1/2,1\}$ defined by
$$
f(x):=\begin{cases}1, & x<0\\1/2, & x=0\\0, & x>0\end{cases}.
$$
Obviosuly, $M:=\{x\in\mathbb{R}: f(x)=1/2\}=\{0\}$.

Now, for $\varepsilon >0$, I am considering the smooth approximation
$$
f^\varepsilon=\eta_\varepsilon * f,
$$
where $\eta\colon\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is the mollifier
$$
\eta(x):=\begin{cases}C\exp\left(\frac{1}{\lvert x\rvert^2-1}\right), & \lvert x\rvert <1\\
0, & \lvert x\rvert\geq 1\end{cases}
$$
and $\eta_\varepsilon(x):=\frac{1}{\varepsilon}\eta\left(\frac{x}{\varepsilon}\right)$.

I would like to know whether
$$
\{x\in\mathbb{R}: f^\varepsilon(x)=1/2\}=M,
$$
i.e., whether the position at which the approcimation $f^\varepsilon$ takes the "middle value" 1/2 remains the same position as that for $f$.

Comment: Look at $g(x) = f(x) - \frac{1}{2}$. This is an odd function. And $\eta$ is even. What follows for $g^{\varepsilon}$? And what does that tell you about $f^{\varepsilon}$?

Comment: If $g$ is odd and $\eta$ is even, then $g^\varepsilon:=\eta_\varepsilon * g$, as a convolution of an odd and an even function, is an odd function.  - Now, we have that $f^\varepsilon=\eta_\varepsilon * f =\eta_\varepsilon * (g+\frac{1}{2})$. I am not sure what this tells me about $f^\varepsilon$.

Comment: Well, $f^{\varepsilon}(x) = g^{\varepsilon}(x) + \frac{1}{2}$. To see that $f^{\varepsilon}(x) = \frac{1}{2}$ *only* for $x = 0$ you need to use a little more about the specific functions involved.

Comment: I do not see why $f^\varepsilon(x)=g^\varepsilon(x)+\frac{1}{2}$. We have that $f^\varepsilon(x)=\eta_\varepsilon\circ f = \eta_\varepsilon\circ (g+\frac{1}{2})=g_\varepsilon+\eta_\varepsilon(1/2)$. Probably, for $\varepsilon>0$ small, the last term vanishes.

Comment: Do you mean $\eta_{\varepsilon} \ast \frac{1}{2}$ there?

Comment: yes, $\eta_\varepsilon * \frac{1}{2}$

Comment: What happens when you mollify a constant function?

Comment: I see what you mean: Nothing happends, i.e. $\eta_\varepsilon * \frac{1}{2}=\frac{1}{2}$. Ok!  - - Another question is: Where do we need that the convolution is odd?

Comment: We don't _need_ it, it's just a simple way to see $g^{\varepsilon}(0) = 0$ without computation.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help!